# Failure on Timescale Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

During Timescale continuous aggregate policy refresh on a defined interval, it throws the below-mentioned errors.

Running on PostgreSQL 13.6 & Timescale 2.5.0

```
2022-02-24 14:01:13.663 [23576] LOG:  refreshing continuous aggregate "aggregate_policy" in window 
2022-02-24 14:01:13.669 [23576] LOG:  job 1012 threw an error
2022-02-24 14:01:13.669 [23576] ERROR:  portal snapshots (0) did not account for all active snapshots (1)
2022-02-24 14:01:13.673 [24936] LOG:  background worker "Refresh Continuous Aggregate Policy [1012]" (PID 23576) exited with exit code 1
```

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Transparency: I work for Timescale

This has been captured as a project issue at https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/4128